# Add exif date to jpeg using filename

Tags: date, jpeg, filenames, batch-processing, exif

I have a bunch (about 1200) of jpg/jpeg files, which have a filename pattern of: IMG-YYYYMMDD-WA####.jpg or .jpeg. None of them have any exif data. I would like to (batch) add exif dates (created, modified, ...) using the date pattern in the filename. Time doesn really matter for me.

I have searched this (and other) forums, but i cannot find anything related to ADDING these dated to jpeg files. I was hoping someone here could help me out.

EDIT: Using Linux (Mint 17,1)

Comment: You didn't mention what system you are on: PC, Mac, Linux ? On a Mac, Created and Modified dates are part of the file metadata (I  imagine the same as for a PC). Anyway to modify those dates you would't be modifying the Exif data, it would be a file system call. Exif dates are File date and time, Date time of Image, and Date time Digitized.

Comment: You are right. Edited my question.

Comment: How do you know there is no Exif data in these files? Have you looked at using ExifTool or a Hex Editor ?

Answer (score 0):

This should not be difficult to write. What you need to create is a filter that:

1. Removes the existing JPEG file APPn header
2. Inserts an EXIF header with the date.

You would not need to mess with the compressed data at all. You're going to need to read a bit of the JPEG standard, just enough to get an idea of the block structure. Do a byte-by-byte copy until you hit an APPn marker.The APPn markers have byte counts so you know how much to skip over. Insert your own EXIF marker into the stream. Then copy the rest of the data.

You're need to read the EXIF standard to figure out how to format the header.

Comment: Sorry, but I have really no clue what you are talking about here. Filter? I know what a JPEG APP# header is, but i am not technical enough to understand how to do what you are saying.

Comment: A fiter is a program that takes some input and transforms it (e.g. sort). You're going to have to read the JPEG standard to see what an APPn marker is and the EXIF standard to see the format of its APPn marker.

Comment: Then still, I have no clue how to do this. I am not a programmer. I cannot imagine that there is no tool around to do things like this. I am definitely not the first person with this kind of problem.